# Jenkins/Git on Windows - cannot clone on master but can clone on slave

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-agent

I have the following setup:

Server A

- Running Windows 7, 64 bit
- Jenkins master as the Local System account.

Server B

- Running Windows 7, 64 bit
- A slave of the Jenkins master.
- The agent is running as a dedicated user LOGON\jenkins.

We are using SSH to access GitHub - this is a requirement we can't change.
We are using the GitHub plugin.

If I initiate a Build on the Windows slave, the slave is able to clone a Git repository successfully.

If I initiate a Build on the Master, I get this error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h git@github.com:MY-PRJ/MY-REPO.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: my-userid@github.build.ge.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

- but the same Build works on the Slave.

Obviously a SSH key issue on the master - but where to look?

Comment: Do you use the same SSH key on multiple servers? https://superuser.com/questions/332510/how-to-transfer-my-ssh-keys-to-another-machine

Comment: Have you put your `LOGON\jenkins` user's (ServerA) `id_rsa.pub` key in the GitHub account the repo is cloning?

Comment: Hi, same SSH key used on multiple servers - the problem is specific to server A only. And yes, ServerA's id_rsa.pub key is in the GitHub account.

Comment: _"Copying a private key is really not a good idea. Having a single key at multiple locations **1**. makes it more vulnerable, **2**. increases risk that you lost control of all the locations, **3**. does not allow you to disable access from just one location. From the security point of view you should generate a new key-pair on every location"_

Comment: evolutionxbox: thank you for the kind security lecture :) however, as the two servers in question are virtual test servers behind a secure firewall on a VPN, and will be spun down once we have finished testing in a day or so, I think I can afford to take the hit on using the same key in multiple (2) servers.

Comment: Is the ssh agent running on the master as well? (to cache the passphrase associated with the private key)

Comment: Yes it is... and problem identified. We eventually tracked this down to the userid that the master was running as, which was Local Service Account. The Agent was running with a specific userid, which had the ssh keys correctly set, but master did not. We switched master to the correct userid, set the ssh keys and hey presto! Git clones. A bit obvious but sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees. Thanks for all the help everyone!